# CppCheck custom rule does not show message

Tags: c++, cppcheck

My cpp program:

```cpp
void f() {
  int x =0;
  x++;
  array[x + 2] = 0;
}
```

[image: My rule file]

[image: output]

I do not understand the summary of the rule file

Comment: What exactly is your question here? The part inside the  pattern tag is a regular expression. Your regular expression is not represented in the code, so there is no way Cppcheck will find this rule here.

Answer (score 0):

I will try and give you a detailed answer. With rule files you can give Cppcheck a regular expression to search for in the scanned code. The regular expression is the part inside the pattern tag.

While Cppcheck will do some changes on the code (a space after every token, ...) it will not interpret your code. So if there is a `x + 2` in the code, the regular expression "3" will never find it. You can limit the way, Cppcheck modifies your code, by adding a tokenlist tag to the rule file, which can have the values raw, normal and simple.

Your regular does not match any part in your code, therefore Cppcheck will not find anything here. Judging from the name you gave the rule file, you want to detect a redundant condition. Even though there is not even a condition in the code, it is also really hard to find something like that with a regular expression.